# PHP : show all rows in MySQL that contain the same value in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying write code in PHP with a Mysql database, and the problem is I want to show all rows with a same column value. for example like this:

```
id  |   Name   | age | Location | type
----+----------+-----+----------+------
 1  | Ane      | 22  |  SG      |  1
 2  | Angi     | 19  |  IND     |  2
 3  | Bobby    | 23  |  PH      |  1
 4  | Denis    | 26  |  IND     |  1
 5  | Jerry    | 21  |  SG      |  1
 6  | Mikha    | 25  |  JP      |  2
```

I want only show the rows with value in column type = 1 or value in column Location and showing as table in html view.

The result what I want is like this:

```
id  |   Name   | age | Location | type
---+----------+-----+----------+------
 1  | Ane      | 22  |  SG      |  1
 3  | Bobby    | 23  |  PH      |  1
 4  | Denis    | 26  |  IND     |  1
 5  | Jerry    | 21  |  SG      |  1
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testuser");
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `usersdata` WHERE `type`='1'");
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

echo "<table class='tmaintable' border='0' cellpadding='3' width='99%' align='center' cellspacing='1'>
<tr class='theader'>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
<td>Location</td>
<td>Type</td>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){              
echo "<tr class='todd'>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;' >" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

But I got errors like this:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in www.myweb.com\users_list\type.php on line 94 << this point "$query" line
>   Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in www.myweb.com\users_list\type.php on line 95 << this point "$result" line
>   Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in www.myweb.com\users_list\type.php on line 109 << this point "while ($row=" line

I was trying understand and still i don't get it, anyone can help me please?! thanks.

Comment: what you are get while running this code?? any error?? something else

Comment: i guess you are getting an array as result. you have to read each row and print them in table.

Comment: What is your current output if any?

Comment: there is no output, i just get a header table only and show thats error in the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
`$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usersdata WHERE type='1'");`
to
`$query = "SELECT * FROM usersdata WHERE type='1'";`

**EDIT**
Just for explanation:
mysqli_query takes 2 arguments: connection and query. I assumed that you wanted to just create query string in this line where this error arouse since it is used one line furter as a query string.

Comment: could you add some words of explanation, so the OP knows *why* this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in bolow lines.
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `usersdata` WHERE `type`='1'");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

You have 2 ways to resolve this.

```
1. $query = "SELECT * FROM `usersdata` WHERE `type`='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

2. $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `usersdata` WHERE `type`='1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It should be working fine

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usersdata` WHERE `type`='1'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "<table class='tmaintable' border='0' cellpadding='3' width='99%' align='center' cellspacing='1'>
    <tr class='theader'>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr class='todd'>";
        echo "<td style='text-align:center;' >" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```